# Are concurrency issues possible when using the WCF Service Behavior attribute set to ConcurrencyMode.Multiple and InstanceContextMode.PerCall?

Tags: c#, wcf, multithreading, nhibernate, transactions

We have a WCF service that makes a good deal of transactional NHibernate calls.  Occasionally we were seeing SQL timeouts, even though the calls were updating different rows and the tables were set to row level locking.

After digging into the logs, it looks like different threads were entering the same point in the code (our transaction using block), and an update was hanging on commit.  It didn't make sense, though, because we believed that the following service class attribute was forcing a unique execution thread per service call:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

We recently changed the concurrency mode to `ConcurrencyMode.Single` and haven't yet run into any issues, but the bug was very difficult to reproduce (if anyone has any thoughts on flushing a bug like that out, let me know!).

Anyway, that all brings me to my question: shouldn't an InstanceContextMode of PerCall enforce thread-safety within the service, even if the ConcurrencyMode is set to multiple?  How would it be possible for two calls to be serviced by the same service instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The only way to have two different WCF clients, i.e., proxies, reference the same instance of your WCF service is to use `InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single`.  This is a poor choice if scaling is an issue, so you want to use `PerCall` if you can.

When you use `PerCall`, *each **CALL** to the WCF service gets its own WCF service instance*.  There's no sharing of the service instance, but that doesn't mean that they don't share the same back-end storage (e.g., database, memory, file, etc.).  Just remember, `PerCall` allows each ***call*** to access your WCF service simultaneously.

The [`ConcurrencyMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx) setting controls the threading model of the service itself.  A setting of `Single` restricts all of the WCF service instances to running on the same thread.  So if you have multiple clients connecting at the same time, they will only be executed one at a time on the WCF service side.  In this case, you leverage WCF to provide synchronization.  It'll work fine, as you have seen, but think of this as having only macro-level control over synchronization - each WCF service call will execute in its entirety before the next call can execute.

Setting `ConcurrencyMode` to `Multiple`, however, will allow all of the WCF service instances to execute simultaneously.  In this case, *you are responsible for providing the necessary synchronization*.  Think of this as having micro-level control over synchronization since you can synchronize only those portions of each call that need to be synchronized.

I hope I've explained this well enough, but here's a snippet of the MSDN documentation for [`ConcurrencyMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx) just in case:

> Setting ConcurrencyMode to Single instructs the system to restrict
>   instances of the service to one thread
>   of execution at a time, which frees
>   you from dealing with threading
>   issues. A value of Multiple means that
>   service objects can be executed by
>   multiple threads at any one time. In
>   this case, you must ensure thread
>   safety.

**EDIT**

You asked

> Is there any performance increase, then, using PerCall vs. Single when using ConcurrencyMode.Single? Or is the inverse true?

This will likely be service dependent.

With `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`, a new service instance is created for each and every call via the proxy, so you have the overhead of instance creation to deal with.  Assuming your service constructor doesn't do much, this won't be a problem.

With `InstanceContextMode.Single`, only one service instance exists for the lifetime of the application, so there is practically no overhead associated with instance creation.  However, this mode allows only one service instance to process every call that will ever be made.  Thus, if you have multiple calls being made simultaneously, each call will have to wait for the other calls to finish before it can be executed.

For what it's worth, here's how I've done this.  Use the `PerCall` instance context with `Multiple` concurrency.  Inside your WCF service class, create static members to manage the back-end data store for you, and then synchronize access to these static members as necessary using the `lock` statement, `volatile` fields, etc.  This allows your service to scale nicely while still maintaining thread safety.

Comment: You definitely nailed my other disconnect.  So using `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`, regardless of InstanceContextMode, means you're using `lock` statements around critical sections and performing other thread-safety/synchronization checks.  Is there any performance increase, then, using `PerCall` vs. `Single` when using `ConcurrencyMode.Single`?  Or is the inverse true?

Comment: This is all great information.  Thanks for being so thorough; I got a lot out of it.

Comment: "Use the PerCall instance context with Multiple concurrency." ConcurrencyMode has no effect on PerCall services as by definition each call from a client gets allocated a new service instance with its own thread: PerCall is always effectively ConcurrencyMode.Single. Of course you will still have to make your shared/static data threadsafe, but a good design will have very little or no static/shared data other than the Database.

Comment: Setting `ConcurrencyMode` to `Single` restricts each instance of the service to a single thread, not all instances of a service to a single thread. Requests will only execute one at a time if the `InstanceContextMode` is also set to `Single`. So, if `InstanceContextMode` is `PerCall` and `ConcurrencyMode` is `Single`, the WCF service will support multiple concurrent clients.

Comment: @Matt Davis, could you please help me out on my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837277/wcf-multiple-concurrency-issue-with-instance-method-call

Answer (score 7):

I believe the answer is the fact that there are multiple threads (on the client side) utilizing the same proxy instance, thus potentially allowing for multiple calls into the same instance. This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/rickrain/archive/2009/06/17/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-2.aspx) has a more detailed explanation.

Comment: That's a great article and I think really illuminates the issue (we cache the proxy at the app domain level on the client side, which multiple web requests use).  So are the options 1) To make the service operations thread-safe and open per-call up to multiple threads or 2) just leave it as single and take the performance hit?  Just want to make sure I'm not missing something!

Comment: Or I guess potentially an option 3 would be to create a new proxy for every request...?

Comment: @Brandon Linton, using a new proxy for each request won't solve the problem if you use `PerCall` instance context and `Multiple` concurrency mode.  In this case, you **must** provide thread-safety yourself whether you create the proxy each time or reuse the same one over and over.

Comment: @MattDavis, according to the post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/17/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-2.aspx, "For PerCall services, every message results in a new instance of your service, so generally there is not a concurrency issue unless you are accessing a shared resource between instances". PerCall resolves thread-safety concerns, Multiple increases throughput.

Comment: @Michael Freidgeim, I know my comment wasn't clear, but I was expressly addressing the idea of a shared back-end resource that each `PerCall` instance accesses.  In that case, `PerCall` provides no thread-safety to the back-end resource.  That must be managed manually.

Answer (score 2):

`InstanceContextMode.PerCall` and `ConcurrencyMode.Single` should be fine if you are not using two way callbacks on the server. In that case you will need to use `ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant` or callback will not be able to get access to locked service instance and a deadlock will occur.

Since its a per call service instance creation it is impossible for other threads or calls to get access to it.  As stated in article mentioned in other answers [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/17/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-2.aspx) such combination can still be a problem if session is creatd on a binding level AND you are using the same service proxy object.

So if you don't use same proxy object or don't have a sessionful binding and dont use two way callbacks to client ( most likely they should be OneWay anyway) `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` and `ConcurrencyMode.Single` should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I think its all depends on the requirement.
If we are going to call the same service so many times then better we can use 
InstanceContextMode is Single and concurrencymode is multiple.