# Difference between ConcurrencyMode "Single"/"Multiple" with InstanceContextMode "PerCall"

Tags: wcf

I've taken a look at the different WCF service behaviors (`ConcurrencyModes/InstanceContextModes`) but don't get the difference between `ConcurrencyMode` "Single"/"Multiple" using `InstanceContextMode` "PerCall". Can anyone help me to understand it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This article on [Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx) does a very good job of explaining the differences in each mode and combination of modes. In particular, it answers your question under the Concurrency section:

> In PerCall instancing, concurrency is not relevant, because each message is processed by a new InstanceContext and, therefore, never more than one thread is active in the InstanceContext.

So the answer is, there *is no* difference between Single and Multiple concurrency if your services are instanced per-call.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already assumed it, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: there is a difference between Single and Multiple concurrency. For PerCall instancing ConcurrencyMode "Multiple" can provide better throughput. See [PerCall / Multi-Threaded Services] http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/17/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 4):

For PerCall instancing ConcurrencyMode "Multiple" can provide better throughput. See [PerCall / Multi-Threaded Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/17/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-2.aspx). The article was referred by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545933/52277).